# NodeJS, TypeScript, Mongoose unable to get document with FindById

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

Well, newbie with NodeJS and Mongoose, will try to get a document from a collection and use a class to manage results as i want to do.

I followed many tutos, but... i don't understand why, with the following code, i always get a null object with a findById() method on a model.

After hours spent, i decide to get help...

So, first i define a Model (simplified version) :

```
import { Schema, Model, model } from 'mongoose';

import { DocumentInterface } from './../interfaces/document-product-interface';
import { ProductClass } from './product-class';

var productSchema: Schema = new Schema(
    {
        _id: {
            type: String,
            required: 'Required _id'
        },
        id: {
            type: String,
            required: 'EAN required'
        },
        product_name: {
            type: String
        }
    }
);

// Scheme methods
productSchema.method('title', ProductClass.prototype.title);

export const Products: Model<DocumentInterface> = model<DocumentInterface>('ProductClass', productSchema);
```

Next, create a class (for business purpose) :

```
import { ProductInterface } from './../interfaces/product-interface';

export class ProductClass implements ProductInterface{
    public _id: String;
    public id: String;
    public product_name_fr?: string;
    public product_name?: string;

public constructor() {}

public title(): string {
  return 'something';
}
}
```

Next... The Document interface :

```
import { Document } from 'mongoose';
import { ProductInterface } from './product-interface';
import { ProductClass } from 'models/product-class';

export interface DocumentInterface extends ProductInterface, Document, ProductClass {}
```

Finally, just a controller, to get a product :

```
 import { Products }  from '../models/product-model';
 import { SoappliProductInterface } from './../interfaces/soappli-product-interface';

 import { Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express';

export class ProductController {
   public get(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        console.log('Search for a product : ' + request.params.ean);

        Products.findById(request.params.ean, (error: any, product: DocumentInterface) => {
            if (error) {
                response.status(500).send( {message: error})
            } else {
                console.log('Product: ' + JSON.stringify(product));
                if (product) {
                    console.log('Product title: ' + product.title);
                    response.status(200).send(product);
                } else {
                    response.status(404).send({message: 'no matches for : ' + request.params.ean})
                }
            }
        });
    }
 }
```

When i run with Postman and use a correct _id, got null for product...

If i remove all classes and interfaces, get the entire document...

What's wrong with this code ?

Thx